# Making a view type environment in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want make an environment that carry view and the view that is going be carried is the ContentView, I made the first codes but since it is view and generic I have issue with generic type for my environment.

Some of Xcode error are like this:

> Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred

> Reference to generic type 'ViewType' requires arguments in <...>

**My goal** is building the environment that can carry a view like ContentView.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Adv_view_sendrApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.rootMirrorContent, ViewType(content: ContentView()))
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.rootMirrorContent) var rootMirrorContent
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .overlay(Text("Hello, world!"))
            .overlay(rootMirrorContent.scaleEffect(0.25).border(Color.black), alignment: .bottomTrailing)
            
    }
}

struct RootMirrorContentEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey { static let defaultValue: ViewType = ViewType(content: <#() -> _#>) }

extension EnvironmentValues {

    var rootMirrorContent: ViewType {
        get { return self[RootMirrorContentEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set(newValue) { self[RootMirrorContentEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }

}

struct ViewType<Content: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
        return content()
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask the purpose of "this"? Just out of curiosity...

Comment: I need to have the rootView as Environment, because when I am going deeper and deeper to child view in deferent views i loss to access what was in ContentView, I could define a view type for each single child view to transfer what was/is in Content View but it takes lots of works and not the best approach, therefore I am thinking having the Environment is the best way.

Comment: I don't think that's a correct way to pass UI like this, Secondly, you can give only Observable objects. I recommend you to play with events and update your UI. I mean to present any fullscreen view on top of root view or modal present with view modifier.

Comment: That won't work, to start the instance that you are showing is different than what you are trying to put in the environment. Learn about ObservableObjects and EnvironmentObjects.